# How can I serialise Rust object to Rust literals using serde?

Tags: rust, serde

I would like to use serde in code generation, embedding some complex nested object iterals into generated code.

I'm not expecting to serde produce anything other than something of the form:

```
const FOO: Foo = Foo {
    bar: 0,
    baz: Baz {
        quux: 1
    }
};
```

(Perhaps with me supplying the `const FOO: Foo =`.)

[Ron](https://docs.rs/ron/0.6.0/ron/) would seem to be the crate to use, but it looks like it doesn't produce the Rust syntax for literal values.

Have I misunderstood its purpose?

Comment: First sentence in the docs: "RON is a simple config format which looks similar to Rust syntax." I guess this makes it pretty clear that it isn't actually Rust syntax.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To literally do what you asked for you need to [write a custom Serde serializer](https://serde.rs/impl-serializer.html). It will be a bit of work to get all the details right. Most literals (e.g. strings, characters and numbers) can be serialized to valid Rust literals using the `Display` implementation of [`proc_macro2::Literal`](https://docs.rs/proc-macro2/1.0.19/proc_macro2/struct.Literal.html), which will take care of escaping special characters, suffixing floating point numbers with `.0` if needed and similar details. However, it looks like implementing a serializer for structs will be up to you.

The most common approach to code generation in Rust is [writing a proc macro](https://doc.rust-lang.org/reference/procedural-macros.html), and using the [quote crate](https://docs.rs/quote) to emit the source code. I don't know enough about your use case to be able to tell whether this would be a useful approach for your problem.